# getApplicationDocumentsDirectory is not working on flutter desktop (windows)

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, desktop

How do I save and open file in flutter desktop on Windows. getApplicationDocumentsDirectory is not working on flutter desktop for windows application

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  print('$directory');
  return directory.path;
}
```

Throw error.

```
Exception has occurred
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider))
```

Comment: You tried this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files ?

Comment: @AlexJean That's not working on Windows application as it work on Android, you may try yourself.

Comment: is that link of any help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741142/flutter-desktop-flutter-desktop-embedding-how-to-save-file-to-a-hard-drive I see guys downvoted you. To me is a bit unfair especially they did not comment why they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desktop plugins to work i found i needed to copy the plugins provided by flutter specifically for desktop into my project. I also updated the yaml configuration.

Source for plugins. 
https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/flutter_plugins/path_provider_fde

Note: i believe these plugins will change and eventually become part of the default package installed.

Things like getApplicationDocumentsDirectory are provided by Flutter, but the windows implementation is currently in development, so you have to provide the additional plugins which have the windows/mac/linux implementation. Which can be found on the flutter desktop pages. (link above)

Below is what my folder looks like.

[image]

And my pubspec.yaml
    `dependencies:
        logger: ^0.9.1
        dependencies:
        auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
        draggable_scrollbar: ^0.0.4
        provider: ^4.0.1
        flutter:
            sdk: flutter
        file_chooser:
        git:
            url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
            path: plugins/file_chooser
            ref: 4ee135c
        path_provider: ^1.5.1
        path_provider_macos: ^0.0.1
        path_provider_fde:
            path: ./plugins/flutter_plugins/path_provider_fde
        window_size:
            path: ./plugins/window_size
        url_launcher: ^5.4.0
        url_launcher_fde:
            path: ./plugins/flutter_plugins/url_launcher_fde`

Answer (score 5):

In pubspec.yaml file add (path_provider: ^1.6.24)
import package in our file (import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';)

Answer (score -1):

```
String _localPath = (await _findLocalPath()) + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';
final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
if (!hasExisted) {
  savedDir.create();
}
```

Pubspec.yami

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  path_provider: ^1.6.8
```

Try to this code dear.

Comment: _findLocalPath() is undefined. which package has this function