# Flutter windows app from windows runner does not save the new file to a path in windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-windows

I am trying to save a file to a path in windows using path_provider: 2.0.14. and everything works fine in debug, even when I use the app that is running by the command
"flutter run --release -d windows"

I mention this app is intended only for Windows.
Antivirus is disabled and the released windows app has all permissions.

What I already tried:
I already tried to see if there are any exceptions. There are none catched.
I already applied an implementation without path_provider. I hardocoded the path just so I see if it saves anything. It does in debug or release when started by the command above but not when started manually from build/windows/Runner/Release directory or from build/windows/Runner/debug

This is the actualy function:

```
void funcExample({required String choseName, required String chosenPath, required UInt8List fileAsBytes,}) {
     final docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(fileAsBytes);

     final docxGeneratedBytes = await someMethodThatChangesDocx(docx);

     final path = "$chosenPath\\$chosenName.docx";
  
     final XFile fileToBeSaved =
     XFile.fromData(Uint8List.fromList(docxGeneratedBytes),name: chosenName);
     await fileToBeSaved.saveTo(path);
}
```

I already tried to save by following snippet:

```
final XFile fileToBeSaved =
      XFile.fromData(Uint8List.fromList(docxGeneratedBytes),name: chosenName);
final newFileWithoutCross = File(path);
await newFileWithoutCross.writeAsBytes(await fileToBeSaved.readAsBytes());
```

When I try to open the release executable from build/windows/Runner/Release this saveTo method from the 'cross_file' library does not work. Also it does not throw any exception.

If we put a breakpoint at line 6: value path turns out to have a value for example: "C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\newFile.docx"

Libraries that I use:
file_picker: 5.2.10
path_provider: 2.0.14
docx_template: 0.3.4
file_selector: 0.9.2+5

flutter doctor --verbose:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086], locale ro-RO)
• Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at C:\Users\Acer\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (3 months ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
• Engine revision 1a65d409c7
• Dart version 2.19.6
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.5)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33627.172
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.199
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.67

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I expect that file is saved fine as it works in debug mode or when is ran by flutter command

Answer (score 0):

Try using this new version [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), also I found this answer might help you [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837253/14709302),
also try this package [path_provider_windows](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_windows) work specific in windows might help you,
otherwise, I recommend you start the issue in the path_provider [Ropositry](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/path_provider/path_provider) with all details to help fix the bug for other by contributors

Comment: Update: I already applied a fake test implementation without path_provider. I hardcoded the path just so I see if it saves anything. It does not.

Comment: I have Updated the answer, try using path_provider_windows package.

Comment: As it says in docs path_provider_windows is endorsed, is already added by path_provider automatically

Comment: I added the issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/130283

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when File object was created initially.
The file objects created using paths from assets in release app should be done in a different way:

```
if (kReleaseMode) {
    file = File('data\\flutter_assets\\lib\\assets\\$templateName.docx');
} else {
    file = File('lib/assets/$templateName.docx');
}
```